# Excel: Reverse VLOOKUP with comparison

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have an original table (the value column is sorted):

```
  name  |   id  | value   
--------+-------+-------
  abc   |   1   |  12
  def   |   2   |  15
  ghi   |   3   |  23
  jkl   |   4   |  29
  mno   |   5   |  31
  pqr   |   6   |  46
```

What I want is a second table like this, where the only manual input is the id lines:

```
            id  | value   
         -------+-------
            1   |  12
            3   |  23
         -------+-------
 TOTAL      5   |  35
```

I manage to get the value column filled with the `VLOOKUP` function.
The TOTAL of the value column is just the sum of the column.

What I want is the id of the TOTAL line to be the id of the line (in the first table) where the sum is greater or equal to the value column. In the example 35 is between 31 and 46 sot the value I need is 5.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a combination of `INDEX` and `MATCH` since the index used for the lookup is after the result.

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!B2:B10, MATCH(B3, Sheet1!C2:C10, 1))
```

This assumes that the first table is in Sheet1 from column A to C and the second table is in Sheet2 (name doesn't matter here) and in columns A and B, where The TOTAL row is in row 3.

`MATCH`'s third argument, `1`, means 'less than', so it looks for something less than or equal to 35.

Comment: Ok, your answer works but I don't understand a few things: 1) if I change 1 to -1 in the MATCH function, I get an error (I should have 6, right?) 2) If I only use the MATCH part, it works as well, not sure why (where does the value come from?)

Comment: @gregseth Intuitively yes, it should be returning 6 if you put `-1`, but the thing is that `MATCH` relies on how the data is sorted. See the [documentation page](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/match-function-HP010062414.aspx). Indeed, to get 6, you'd have to sort the value column by descending order to get 6. Similarly, if the value column is not in ascending order, you won't be able to get 5. Secondly, if you use only match (without the third parameter), it will default to `1`.

Comment: I was missing the descending order part. Thank you.